# How can I best limit the decimal places to 5 or shorten the longer ones?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a file with various characters and either words as well as numbers. These numbers can be integers like a 1 or 12 (as an example) or they have a comma and countless digits after the comma.
for example:

> ",{"n":"Box","p":[-4.0,4.0,0.0],"r":[270.0,0.0,0.0],"s":[1.0,1.000006,1.000006],"c":[0.448529363,0.4280135,0.412251264],"m":"wood_14"}"

The file is read with File.ReadAllText and then passed to NewtonsoftJson via JsonProperty accordingly
for example:

```
[JsonProperty("s")]
public double[] Scale
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

For example, with Scale, I want to limit the decimal places to a maximum of 5 digits.
Is this possible and if so, how?
I have been trying for days with different things, but nothing has worked yet.

My idea was to intervene in the string I build first before passing that to Json there. But unfortunately this does not work. I tried it with regular expression like Notepadd++ makes for example.

(edit)

Comment: Is using regular expressions a requirement? because the API provides [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0)

Comment: You are going to need to provide some better specs than _"I have a long string with various characters and either words as well as numbers. These numbers can be integers like a 1 or 12 (as an example) or they have a comma and countless digits after the comma"_.  Do you need to parse numbers out of strings? How do you know which numbers are parsed which way. What did you want to do with that regex you show? Note that by adding the hat char at the beginning and the dollar sign at the end you are saying that the only thing you are about are strings exactly match your pattern, nothing else in them

Comment: @Cleptus: no regular expression isn't requirement, but Math.Round doesn't work.

Comment: @Flydog57: I mean a string like this: ",{\"n\":\"Box\",\"p\":[-4.0,4.0,0.0],\"r\":[270.0,0.0,0.0],\"s\":[1.0,1.000006,1.000006],\"c\":[0.448529363,0.4280135,0.412251264],\"m\":\"wood_14\"}"
Notepadd++ can find and replace to reduce the precision of the digits

Comment: @defiant2369: edit your qustion if you provide more information, don't hide it in the comment section.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell with all the escaped characters, but that looks like JSON. Instead of looking at the string directly in the debugger, look at the debuggers _Text Viewer_ and copy/paste the result into your question (available in the dropdow from the magnifying glass icon). Deserializing the JSON (using `decimal` types) and then directly manipulating the values will be way better than using Regex

Comment: @Flydog57 It is correct, the file is read in with Json and the values are passed in the appropriate places using JsonProperty. But first I build a string with File.ReadAllText. 
I have adjusted my text accordingly above.

Comment: "My idea was to intervene in the string I build first before passing that to Json there" Do you want it to serialize or deserialize? Do you have json already or you want to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want it to serialize or deserialize. So I made code for both cases. You have to leave one variant or another

```
public class a
{
    private double[] val;
    
    [JsonProperty("s")]
    public double[] Scale
    {

        get {    return val;
                 // or
                 val?.Select(v => Math.Round(v, 5)).ToArray();  }
        set { 
                 val=value;
                 //or
                val = value?.Select(v => Math.Round(v, 5)).ToArray(); 
        }
    }
}
```

if you want it in many properties you can make it as a function

Comment: Sometimes things can be so easy. And sometimes you go round in circles. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I just had to find out that this is not possible. The program now finds duplicate objects that are not present. 
I have to edit the string before I pass it to Json.

Comment: @defiant2369 ???  What my code has to do with dublicate objects? it is just array of numbers.

Comment: @defiant2369 If you have another problem , create another post.  Only one thing in a time is allowed here

Comment: Sorry Serge, was my fault. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`double.ToString()` will do it.

```
const double d = 0.123456789;
string s = d.ToString("G5");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

That outputs `0.12346`, showing that it rounds the 5 to 6.

Documentation for [Double.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-double-tostring(system-string)) shows much more detailed examples of how to format numbers.

The number format (i.e. decimal separator) is culture-specific. If you want to use the current culture, then the above will work. If you always want a comma as the decimal separator, you'll have to call the overload that accepts an `IFormatProvider` for the specific culture.